# Export Excel file as HTML [preferably via VBA]

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, export

So it was finally time for me to sign up here.. (:

I need to export an Excel file or preferrably a part of it to a newly created HTML file. Using VBA and PublishObjects.Add I have an export. However cells containing following special characters < > " turn out as `&lt; &gt; &amp;` in that HTML file. I don't want that. I would like to execute JavaScript contained in cells in the HTML file! It is just alerts (for now).

Is there a way to prevent special characters from being translated as shown above?

I could use VBA and open the HTML as text file to replace characters but I think its not a reliable solution. I probably need more than alerts in the future which would further complicate things (edit HTML header, add more complex scripts etc.). Are there better ways to export my file as HTML and include/ add JavaScript?

I tried different VBA tools from the web to have more control over HTML creation but none of them provided a good copy of my file. The file is rather complex.

The solution needs to be automated.
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: File > Save as html page which allows you to also save a specified range and update when that range is updated. It is pretty verbose in the html output. You could record a macro for this as a starting point. I have tested if you have the html entities issue you are describing above.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But with save as HTML page I encounter the same problem as VBA PublishObjects.Add. Special character in cell values do not remain.

Comment: What happens if you entity encode those first? And can you give steps to reproduce?  I just tested with <10 in a cell and had no issue. Excel 2019.

Comment: Not sure I understand the first question. If I write `&amp` in the cell it remains just that. To reproduce just put <script> </script> in a Cell and in Source code it will change when saved as HTML. In browser it will be displayed as <script> </script> but its not running the code.

Comment: Can you write the content to an htmlfile object?

Comment: An example screenshot of the content you want to export would be useful here.  Typically when you export a range to HTML you're not exporting content which is "raw" HTML.

Comment: I have uploaded a sample. Button alerts where added by hand for illustration purpose. I discovered that all the `&nbsp` make it hard to click the buttons. Not Ideal either. https://www.file.io/download/7fUmL6pZKmPf

Comment: So... I want to replace any unwanted HTML entities and edit the HTML document as HTMLdocument. How do I read the whole HTMLdocument back into a string? My code so far: https://pastebin.com/KgYGb5ep

Comment: I found out that its possible to read the whole HTMLdocument with HTML.body.parent.element.outerHTML but its not possible to write it ??

Comment: you can write to the htmlfile object.